# NGINX prevent caching JSON files

Tags: nginx, caching

I have a web application running on NGINX.

Iam trying to prevent NGINX from caching JSON,JS,CSS files.

I have this configuration:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  proxy_connect_timeout       300;
  proxy_send_timeout          300;
  proxy_read_timeout          300;
  send_timeout                300;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  location ~* /.(css|js|json)$ {
    expires -1;
    add_header Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache;
  }
}
```

And still when I look in my broweser I see that the files are (disk cache).

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

I tried using just expires -1;
Tried appling this filter just for JSON files.
Tried with just no-cache header

And I cant make it to not serve the files from cache.

Comment: You have used `/.` in the regular expression, where you should use `\.`. The first matches any character following a `/`, whereas the second matches a literal `.`.

Comment: @RichardSmith this is the right answer can you set it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

You could set it to bypass it:

```
location / {
    # your configurations
    # ...

    if ($request_uri ~* \.(json|js|css)$) {
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;
        expires off;
    }
}
```